# Can I create a SharePoint 2013 list from an InfoPath 2013 form

Tags: infopath, custom-list

I have developed my way into a corner and need help. I know a lot about SharePoint but just started using InfoPath 2013. I began working on a InfoPath filler form (needing the InfoPath client). I built this with the thought that I would be able to publish it to SharePoint and create a new custom list based on the forms schema. I am coming to find out that I may have ran down the wrong path.

What I am looking for is conformation of my error or a way to build a list based on my beautiful form.

The other related question is can I use a filler form with a SharePoint list?

Answer (score 0):

Form filler forms are associated with Form Libraries in SharePoint, not lists. You haven't backed yourself into a corner too far, in general:

- Create a new form library in your SharePoint site.
- Create any fields required for metadata purposes.
- In your form, tell it to submit to your newly created library.